# Definition of Vector Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why is the definition of a vector subspace required to be closed under *scalar* multiplication and not vector multiplication?

Since we require closure over vector addition, why not vector multiplication?

Context: I was asked to prove that anti-symmetric matrices form a vector subspace of all matrices. I proved for addition, but then got stuck under showing vector multiplication. Then realized the definition of subspace was only for scalar multiplication, which made this question obvious.

Comment: How do you define the multiplication between two vectors in $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Matrix spaces have more structure than general vector spaces do.  In a general vector space, there need be no way to multiply two vectors.

Comment: Good point. I suppose one could take the cross-product so that output is also in R^3 allow for closure

Comment: ok so a vector space does not have to form a group/field -- if I recall my discrete maths from high school correctly?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Thank you all. That has answered my question, but I'll leave it open if anyone wants to share some insight as an answer for future people with the same question.

Comment: @SanjitRaman A vector space with an additional vector multiplication operation is known as an [Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is defined as a triple $(V,+,\cdot)$, where $V$ is your set of vectors, and

$$+:V\times V\to V\quad\text{and}\quad\cdot : \mathbb{F}\times V\to V$$

are your operations of *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication* (satisfying certain axioms). This tells you right of the bat that we are not guaranteed that there even exists some sort of vector multiplication, as that is not one of our operations. Now certain spaces, such as the vector space of $n\times n$ matrixes for example, have additional properties, however those are in addition to their definitions as vector spaces.

Now let us look at the definition of a vector subspace. We can define it as a triple $(U,+,\cdot)$, where $U\subseteq V$, and $+$ and $\cdot$ are the relevant restrictions of the operations on $V$ to $U$, such that $U$ is closed under these operations. But now thing about what this means. Since the operations already satisfy most properties of vector space operations, as $V$ is a vector space, what you're really doing when checking closure is checking whether $(U,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space. Thus a subspace is really just a nonempty subset which is also a vector space! It therefore does not make sense to consider some possibly undefined notion of vector multiplication, but the closure of the operations already defined is all that could potentially stop it from being a vector space.